# Keras callback execution order?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to understand Keras callback execution order. Suppose we pass multiple callbacks to model.fit(), each has a `on_epoch_end` method. So the moment we reach the end of an epoch, in which order will the callback functions be executed? Does the main process spawn multiple child-process and assign one to each callback?

It'd nice if the documentations are more detailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be called in the order you've added them.
If you look at the implementation of [CallbackList](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py) class which manage your callbacks, you will see it's iterating by order of appearance.
For example here in [on_epoch_end](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L151).

Also, this is how the class is used in [training loop](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L109) and it does not seems that a separate process is spawn.

Comment: Thanks! That makes the order clear. As a side note, will a separate python process be spawned to handle all callbacks functions? I ask because when I kill the main training process by `ctrl+c`, I can see my callback is still running, and I have to use `kill PID` to stop that.

Comment: I've added some details on how the callach is used in traininin loop. My guess is that you're using Tensorflow as backed which may execute the callbacks differently. The keras implementation does not seem to spawn different process. It could be also. related to GPU resource not released properly.

Comment: Actually, I'm using tf.keras and I'm using tf2.1 for that. Maybe things are different, I'll take a look. Thanks

Comment: All the processes (callbacks and the main training loop) stops as soon as you stop training. The callbacks are executed when the fit function is called. I am using tf2.1 and tf.keras. This is what's happening at my side.

Answer (score 0):

1. They will be executed in the order they are specified in your
   callbacks list inside the model.fit()
2. child process is not created by a parent to perform execution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).